# php what's better to use in isset() functions

Tags: php

I need help with isset() function. I do not know what its return value is.
Is it better to write?

```
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
  }
```

or

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: login.php");
 }
```

Please help

Comment: its boolean, http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php, so i would go with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for both you can have:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != "") {
   header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds silly but it is actually the real issue to me. For over 10 years with PHP, I always want to find a want to shorten my code when isset function involved. And I have my solution for this `isset` issue. For your particular case, it should be:

- Using `empty`:

  if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
      header("Location: login.php");
  }

Answer (score 0):

Its a Boolean ( true/false )

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   header("Location: login.php");
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php